# Creating A react component which can be nested

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a component which can be reused in another component.Suppose i have a component like this

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-md-4/6/7'>
                <div className='bg-dark'>
                    .......... Content Goes Here .............
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then i want to use the component like this...

```
    import React from 'react';

export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container col md={4}>
                    .......... Content Goes Here .............
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

I cant achieve that .It can be somewhat `{this.state.children}` but dont know how can achieve it

Comment: Does this answer your question https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit the `Container` to render children:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-md-4/6/7'>
                <div className='bg-dark'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
<Container col md={4}>
    Hello, world!
</Container>
```

The `children` prop is explained in detail here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

## Props.children

```
const Wrapper = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>
const Inner = (props) => <Wrapper>some text or component</Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access using `this.props.children` because it's class based component. if it's functional component access using `props.children`

```
export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-md-4/6/7'>
                <div className='bg-dark'>
                   {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```